# Проверка версии

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Такая проблема - в index.php есть объявление массивов -> [], как сделать проверку на версию php? Чтобы если версия ниже 5.4 - скрипт выводил сообщение и прекращал работу.

Comment: [Это][1] подойдет?

 [1]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.phpversion.php

Comment: Проблема не в том, чтобы узнать версию - а в том, что php выдает parse error на объявление массива.

Comment: оставьте в index.php только код проверки и инклюда файла, в котором есть такая конструкция

Comment: Об этом я догадался. Просто подумал - может еще варианты есть.

Comment: @woland, с выносом проблемного кода в отдельный файл - классическое решение. Но можно воспользоваться одним из [неявных][1] [вызовов][2] кода, которые позволяют спрятать этот проблемный код от анализатора при компиляции

 [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/215139/
 [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/215817/

Comment: Интересно, зачем? Это же не пользовательское приложение, которое выполняется в разных окружениях. А если скрипт пойдет в общий доступ, то достаточно написать в требованиях версию РНР. Уж разработчик разберется, использовать/исправлять/выкинуть или нет.

Answer (score 1):

У себя делаю так:

```
<?php

if(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '<')) 
{
     require_once ("альтернативный код"); 
}
else
{
    require_once ("код с []");
}
```

Comment: Ну ЁПРСТ - читайте комментарии.

Comment: Ну так не намного сложнее, update. Хотя вы уже и сами догадались.

Comment: Хотя ИМХО это бред так писать, если нужна поддержка ранних версий, так лучше вообще не использовать возможности, которые в них не поддерживаются (если это, конечно, не библиотека какая-нибудь). Так что я бы лучше забил на старые.